# uTorrent Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, utorrent

I wrote myself a script based off another one that I found and I'm having trouble figuring out why it's not working.

How it is supposed to work is once a torrent has finished downloading, it runs the script and grabs the Label on the torrent. For testing, I was downloading a song with the label of Music.
When it gets to the point at :copyfile, it won't move it into the correct directory. Instead of moving into F:\Completed Torrents\Music, it just moves into F:\Completed Torrents.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing because I've looked through it thrice already and it's driving me crazy. The script is below.

```
@echo off
title Liam's torrent-file script
rem Parameter usage: fromdir torrent-name label kind [filename]
rem corresponds to uTorrents flags: %D %N %L %K %F 
echo *********************************************
echo Run on %date% at %time%

set fromdir=%1
set name=%2
set label=%3
set kind=%4
set filename=%5
set savepartition="F:\Completed Torrents"
set winrar="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
set torrentlog="F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\torrentlog.txt"
set handledlog="F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\handled_torrents.txt"
set errorlog="F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\ErrorLog.txt"
set label_prefix=""

echo Input: %fromdir% %name% %label% %kind% %filename%

rem Check if the label has a sub label by searching for \
if x%label:\=%==x%label% goto skipsublabel
rem Has a sub label so split into prefix and suffix so we can process properly later
echo sub label
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\ " %%a in ("%label%") do set label_prefix=%%a&set label_suffix=%%b
rem add the removed quote mark
set label_prefix=%label_prefix%"
set label_suffix="%label_suffix%
echo.prefix  : %label_prefix%
echo.suffix  : %label_suffix%
goto:startprocess

:skipsublabel
echo Skipped Sub Label
goto:startprocess

:startprocess
echo %date% at %time%: Handling %label% torrent %name% >> %handledlog%

rem Process the label
if %label%=="Movies" goto known
if %label%=="Music" goto known
if %label_prefix%=="TV" goto TV


rem Last resort
rem Double underscores so the folders are easier to spot (listed on top in explorer)
echo Last Resort
set todir=%savepartition%\Unsorted\__%name%
if %kind%=="single" goto copyfile
if %kind%=="multi" goto copyall
GOTO:EOF

:known
echo **Known Download Type - %label%
set todir=%savepartition%\%label%\%name%
echo todir = %todir%
GOTO:process

:TV
echo **Known Download Type - %label%
set todir=%savepartition%\%label_prefix%\%label_suffix%
echo todir = %todir%
GOTO:process

:process
rem If there are rar files in the folder, extract them.
rem If there are mkvs, copy them. Check for rars first in case there is a sample.mkv, then we want the rars
if %kind%=="single" goto copyfile
if exist %fromdir%\*.rar goto extractrar
if exist %fromdir%\*.mkv goto copymkvs
if %kind%=="multi" goto copyall
echo Guess we didnt find anything
GOTO:EOF

:copyall
echo **Type unidentified so copying all
echo Copy all contents of %fromdir% to %todir%
xcopy %fromdir%\*.* %todir% /S /I /Y
GOTO:EOF

:copyfile
rem Copies single file from fromdir to todir
echo Single file so just copying
echo Copy %filename% from %fromdir% to %todir%
xcopy %fromdir%\%filename% %todir%\ /S /Y
GOTO:EOF

:copymkvs
echo Copy all mkvs from %fromdir% and subdirs to %todir%
xcopy %fromdir%\*.mkv %todir% /S /I /Y
GOTO:EOF

:extractrar
echo Extracts all rars in %fromdir% to %todir%. 
rem Requires WinRar installed to c:\Program files
if not exist %todir% mkdir %todir%
IF EXIST %fromdir%\subs xcopy %fromdir%\subs %todir% /S /I /Y
IF EXIST %fromdir%\subtitles xcopy %fromdir%\subtitles %todir% /S /I /Y
call %winrar% x %fromdir%\*.rar *.* %todir% -IBCK  -ilog"%todir%\RarErrors.log"
IF EXIST %fromdir%\*.nfo xcopy %fromdir%\*.nfo %todir% /S /I /Y
GOTO:EOF
```

**EDIT**
Also, for some reason, on line 39 nothing prints to the log. For those who wish to see the code with line numbers: http://hastebin.com/juqokefoxa.dos

Comment: your code has more lines with quoting issues than correct lines. And as you might know, SO is a place for `'professional and enthusiast programmers'`, not copycats.

Comment: You appear to have a lot of `echo` statements showing the events in the processing. Now ere you to share those with us, we'd be in a better position to help...

Comment: @Endoro If you read the first line, "based off another one". I never admitted to being a professional however I enjoy programming.
Magoo Unfortunately it doesn't work like that... As soon the torrent finishes, it runs the batch script. No matter how many pause statements you put in it, it will just bypass them. You can't even see the window.

Comment: Try to narrow down your question, or focus in on specific lines that are not behaving as expected.  You can't expect a good answer if your question has a hundred lines of code and you just say "it's not working".  For example, there are many ways to reach :copyfile, but we have no way of knowing how it got there in your case, thus no way of knowing the value of %todir%.  Try deleting all unnecessary code for your specific case, and then edit your question so you only need to present a dozen lines of code at most.  Odds are you'll have found the problem  yourself by that time.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Before You Ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before)

Comment: not sure this helps,  but if utorrent is still using the file, it will not let you copy it to another dir. At least this is my experience. I usually have to stop the torrent then move file. not sure if that matters when doing it by a script or not..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of bits for ya:

1) Likely, your script isn't moving the files. Preferences / Directories has an option to move downloads when completed. verify that these settings aren't doing the file moving.

2) uTorrent locks the files on completion so that seeding can continue. To change this behavior, go to Preferences / Advanced and set bt.read_only_on_complete to false

3) you will still be foiled because "Run this program when a torrent finishes" doesn't really do what it says. It runs the program as downloading reaches 100%, but while uTorrent is still either moving the file or seeding. See my bug report [here](http://forum.utorrent.com/topic/96725-run-this-program-when-a-torrent-finishes-doesnt-really-do-what-it-says/).

A quick summary of the post, just in case that post gets deleted: you have to set the command in "Run this program when a torrent changes state:", add a %S parameter and check that %S == 11

4) Just a tip from my attempt at doing something very similar: when you set the variables from the arguments, add a tilde (%~1 instead of %1). This will strip the quotes off and let us more easily build command lines with the variables later.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the log is not being written to.  Try this as a test and see if it writes to the log.

If it doesn't there there is some other fundamental problem.

```
@echo off
title Liam's torrent-file script
rem Parameter usage: fromdir torrent-name label kind [filename]
rem corresponds to uTorrents flags: %D %N %L %K %F 
echo *********************************************
echo Run on %date% at %time%

set "fromdir=%~1"
set "name=%~2"
set "label=%~3"
set "kind=%~4"
set "filename=%~5"
set "savepartition=F:\Completed Torrents"
set "winrar=C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
set "torrentlog=F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\torrentlog.txt"
set "handledlog=F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\handled_torrents.txt"
set "errorlog=F:\Torrent Scripts\logs\ErrorLog.txt"
set "label_prefix="

set "handledlog=%userprofile%\desktop\handled_torrents.txt"

>> "%handledlog%" echo Input: "%fromdir%" "%name%" "%label%" "%kind%" "%filename%"
>> "%handledlog%" echo %date% at %time%: Handling "%label%" torrent "%name%"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same results. :(

Comment: Then your batch file is **not running** or your log file has a permission issue.  Try the edited code above again and see if a log file is created on your desktop.

Comment: I know the batch file runs because it does the movement part of the script (just not to the right folder).

Comment: No, it's not running.  Unless you tested the above and it created the log file.  If it doesn't create the log file then Utorrent is most likely moving the file to the completed folder by itself.